# Where to get pure C++ Lame MP3 encoder - PCM to MP3 example?

Tags: c++, mp3, lame

So all I need is a simple function that sets it up (eating incoming PCM RATE (for example: rate near to 44100) It's channels (for example: 2) and -bits (for example: 16) and desirable 128 kb\s rate) and another one that takes PCM data and encodes it into pure MP3 frames.

I know it looks like a silly homework task but I assure you - it is not.

I hope it will be of help to all C++ developers starting with MP3s.

So can anybody please help me with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the example I gave in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495420/is-there-any-lame-c-wraper-simplifier-working-on-linux-mac-and-win-from-pure-c/2496831#2496831) for the basic usage of Lame. It should contain everything you need.

Comment: best one I've seen for 6 month!)

Answer (score 3):

It's a long time since i messed with this, but Lame lib contains all you need to do it, check out [lame.h](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/include/lame.h?revision=1.181&view=markup) , there is some [test code](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/test/lame_test.cpp?revision=1.1&view=markup) you could look into.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd be looking at ffmpeg's [libavcodec](http://ffmpeg.org/developer.html).  There's an example file containing an [audio_encode_example](http://www.koders.com/default.aspx?s=libavcodec+audio_encode_example&submit=Search&la=*&li=*) which ought to be more or less what you're looking for.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program).

Note that not all ffmpeg packagings include mp3 codec support (patent issues) by default, although there's usually some simple way of enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

[GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) should definitely be able to handle this.
If you are on Windows you can use the [GStreamer Winbuilds](http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/doku.php) to get started.