# How can I convert wav to MP3 programmatically in C++?

Tags: c++, mp3

How can I convert wav to MP3 programatically in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495420/is-there-any-lame-c-wraper-simplifier-working-on-linux-mac-and-win-from-pure-c

Comment: They are similar questions, but not exact duplicates. This question assumes no knowledge of where to begin, whereas the other question knows about one particular encoder and asks for a simpler way to use it. Searchers who don't already know what Lame is will not recognize that question as something that would provide an answer for this question.

Comment: programatically - as opposed to...

Comment: Presumably as opposed to asking (on SuperUser) for an application that can do so.

Answer (score 3):

You would use an encoder, preferably as a pre-made library as doing your own is a bit of an undertaking.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495420/is-there-any-lame-c-wraper-simplifier-working-on-linux-mac-and-win-from-pure-c) for an example of how to use the [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) open source encoder.

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg ( http://ffmpeg.org/ ) does this from a UNIX command line.  So if you can open a pipe to the command line in C++, you can use ffmpeg for the conversion.