# How to decode mp3 into wav using lame in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, lame

I learned how to encode wav into an mp3 using `lame_encode_buffer_interleaved` from this question: [Is there any LAME c++ wraper\simplifier (working on Linux Mac and Win from pure code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495420/is-there-any-lame-c-wraper-simplifier-working-on-linux-mac-and-win-from-pure-c)

Now I want to decode the mp3 back into wav. I know there's `lame_decode` but I don't know how to use it since it requires two pcm buffers (`pcm_l` and `pcm_r`). I don't understand how to put them together into a well-formed wav file, because I don't really know how they works.

Now can someone provide a simple working example on decoding an mp3 into a wav using lame in C/C++?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look into the lame frontend source code. Start at the `lame_decoder()` function in the `.../frontend/lame_main.c` file, it decodes an MP3 file and writes the wave header.

Comment: But how to use lame_decoder(). I don't see any .h file for it :(