# Reading PCM samples in LAME - need explanation of source code

Tags: c, lame

Subsequent to my question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14603974/350685), further investigation into `LAME` with `gdb` revealed that at any given time, only 576 samples are read from the input `pcm` file. However, these samples are used to populate a 2304 1D or 2*1152 2D array. It is this conversion that I am not able to understand. I am posting the relevant code here and request an explanation. I have explained parts of the code and inserted questions into the code as `???`.

```
  samples_read = read_samples_pcm(global.musicin, insamp, num_channels * samples_to_read);
  /* global.musicin = FILE pointer to input pcm file.
   * insamp is a 1D int array of [2*1152] size.
   * num_channels = 1. samples_to_read = 576. */
    if (samples_read < 0) {
        return samples_read;
    }
    p = insamp + samples_read;
    samples_read /= num_channels;  /*samples_read = 576 after this step. prior to this it is optimized out.*/
    if (buffer != NULL) { /* output to int buffer */
        if (num_channels == 2) {
            for (i = samples_read; --i >= 0;) {
                buffer[1][i] = *--p;
                buffer[0][i] = *--p;
            }
        }
        else if (num_channels == 1) {
            memset(buffer[1], 0, samples_read * sizeof(int));
            for (i = samples_read; --i >= 0;) {
                buffer[0][i] = *--p;
                /*??? Is this line a fancy way of copying first 576 samples of insamp into buffer[0]?*/
            }
        }
        else
            assert(0);
    }
```

The function `read_samples_pcm` is defined so:

```
static int
read_samples_pcm(FILE * const musicin, int sample_buffer[2304], int samples_to_read)
{
    int     samples_read;

    samples_read = sf_read_int((SNDFILE *) musicin, sample_buffer, samples_to_read);

#if 0
    switch (global.pcmbitwidth) {
    case 8:
        for (i = 0; i < samples_read; i++)
            sample_buffer[i] <<= (8 * sizeof(int) - 8);
        break;
    case 16:  /*input pcm is 16 bit say.*/
        for (i = 0; i < samples_read; i++)
            sample_buffer[i] <<= (8 * sizeof(int) - 16); /*??? what is going on? */
        break;
    case 24:
        for (i = 0; i < samples_read; i++)
            sample_buffer[i] <<= (8 * sizeof(int) - 24);
        break;
    case 32:
        break;
    default:
        if (silent < 10) {
            error_printf("Only 8, 16, 24 and 32 bit input files supported \n");
        }
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    return samples_read;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /*??? Is this line a fancy way of copying first 576 samples of insamp
>   into buffer[0]?*/

Basically, yes. It's just copying the data end->start rather than the usual start->end order. I'm not sure but I think some people prefer this for memory cache performance reasons.

> /*??? what is going on? */

It's scaling the 16-bit input to a 32-bit number. Let's walk through it:

```
sample_buffer[i] <<= (8 * sizeof(int) - 16);
```

If sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, 8 * 4 - 16 = 16. Thus, shift the 16-bit number left by 16 in order to scale it to a 32-bit number. If sizeof(int) is 8 bytes, 8 * 8 - 16 = 48. If ints are 64-bit, a left shift by 48 bits is necessary.

I'm not sure if I've answered all your questions here. Feel free to follow up.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the reply. The bit-shift makes sense. However, in the copying part, don't you think that the copy operation is start->end as well? `p = insamp + samples_read` which means `p` points to `insamp[576]`. now in the copy operation, for the first `i`, `buffer[0][575] = insamp[575]`. am i correct?

Comment: The copy operation appears to be end->start. Perhaps it was misleading when I wrote "the usual start->end order". I didn't mean that this code was doing the copy start->end. Rather, I meant that (I believe) start->end is how most people intuitively implement and visualize a memcpy operation (though, fun fact: memcpy is not guaranteed to copy in any particular order).