# Audio speed changes on converting WAV to MP3

Tags: c, mp3, wav, lame

I create a `WAV` (`PCM`) to `MP3` converter. But the output is too fast.

This is the code, that converts the encoding.

```
FILE *pcm = fopen(in_path, "rb");
FILE *mp3 = fopen(out_path, "wb");

int read, write;    

const int PCM_SIZE = 8192;
const int MP3_SIZE = 8192;

short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

lame_t lame = lame_init();
lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, sampleRate);
lame_set_brate(lame, byteRate);
lame_set_num_channels(lame, channels);
lame_set_mode(lame, MONO);
lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
lame_init_params(lame);

do {
    read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
    if (read == 0)
    {
        write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    }
    else
    {
        write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    }
    fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);
} while (read != 0);

lame_close(lame);
fclose(mp3);
fclose(pcm);
```

The parameters `sampleRate`, `byteRate` and `channels` are read from the WAV header.

I believe something is missing in the code....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting it up to encode a mono stream (`lame_set_mode(lame, MONO);`) but providing the data as if it were interleaved stereo.

If it's a mono stream, then remove the `2*` from `fread`, to read enough samples for a single channel; and call `lame_encode_buffer` rather than `lame_encode_buffer_interleaved`, with the right-hand channel pointer set to either `NULL` or `pcm_buffer`, to encode just one channel.

If it's a stereo stream, then don't set the mode to mono. You probably shouldn't do this anyway; I think it detects the mode based on the number of channels.

Also, as I mentioned when I [wrote that code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496831/204847), you should check for and handle errors if you're using it in a real application. It's a very basic example.

Comment: Thanks! I found your code, and changes everthing to make it works! I thought that setting MONO will make works. But now I realize that setting one buffer as NULL will fix it!

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with Mono sound, remember to set the channel to 1

```
if (channel == 1) {
    lame_set_num_channels(lame, 1);
    lame_set_mode(lame, MONO);
}
```

Also update the encoding function

```
if (channel == 1) {
    write = lame_encode_buffer(lame, pcm_buffer, NULL, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
}else{
    write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Like, 3 years later, but after spending all night trying to fix this, your code did it! Thank you!