# Basic LAME encoding changes pitch

Tags: mp3, pcm, lame

I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496831/694195) for a basic use of `libmp3lame`, using a 30sec long 440Hz sine wave PCM at 44.1kHz (generated with Audacity) as the input.

The output produced was 15 seconds of a higher pitched tone. I also tried a 48kHz PCM of human speech which came out perfectly (naturally in that case I changed `lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100)` to `48000`.

Why would the sine wave change so much and the speech be correct? What do I need to change in the code for the wave to be encoded correctly?

**EDIT:** It's something to do with the input being mono. Now I just cant seem to find how to specify that with libmp3lame.

Comment: how many channels does the output file have? 1 or 2?