# How does PCM files converts to MP3 using lame encoder

Tags: c++, c, lame

I am converting the wave file into mp3 using lame encoder.
I have reached [this answer (Mike Seymour)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496831/10862144) which does the work very nicely. I am looking to convert this into a c++ equivalent code.

[This answer (trodevel)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872799/10862144) Does the c++ equivalent conversion of the code but I am unable to understand this one.

What I am looking for is to understand how [Mike Seymour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496831/10862144) works?

Why he used a `pcm_buffer` *(size 4 * 8192 bytes)* & `mp3_buffer` *(size 8192 bytes)*?
Is the ratio between (pcm size) : (mp3 size) = 4:1?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe if you comment under his answer, he might tell you right away.

Comment: You'll be lucky to get a reply from Mike Seymour, given that he hasn't visited Stack Overflow since 2015.

Comment: Yes he is not active. and I cannot comment on that post needs some points.

Comment: **does the work very nicely.** Then Why are you not using it? For understanding you can use debug mode and check how it flows. Show us your code if you have made changes. Also refer this [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for future.

Comment: Note that Mike's answer states that he knocked up the example quickly.  It's quite possible that the buffer sizes he chose will not always work.  If you read the comments in the LAME header file above `lame_encode_buffer`, it offers a worst-case estimate, which turns out to be 16200 bytes for a _single channel_ input of 8192 PCM samples.  Why don't you simply use his answer as a basic tool to get started, and then write your own original code in C++?  You should trust the documentation in LAME above anything else.

Comment: @paddy. Can you post the link for documentation here? I could not find docs in the website

Comment: As I said, read the LAME header: _i.e._ `lame.h`