# FFmpeg C API documentation/tutorial

Tags: c, ffmpeg, documentation

I am trying to find documentation to use the FFmpeg C API. It seems that only command line documentation is available.

Is there any good documentation/tutorials/links available?

Comment: I do not think that this question should be closed. There is not much official documentation for any of the FFmpeg libraries, and the fact that this question has so many upvotes and favorites shows that it is useful to the community.

Comment: I have to agree with you, some of the most useful and interesting posts that I find are 'closed as not constructive'.

Comment: Here is a minimal runnable C example that synthesizes some video: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale/36487785#36487785

Comment: The docs seem to be located at https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.4/index.html

Answer (score 54):

I've been keeping the Dranger ffmpeg tutorials up to date here: https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial

I've tried to keep the code changes minimal while fixing bugs and rewriting deprecated parts.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the best one I have found so far.  It deals with a lot of the quirks of the API and shows you how to build a working video player using SDL and libavformat/libavcodec.

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: outdated though, see the other answers...

Comment: FYI the dranger.com one appears to have been updated in 2015

Answer (score 13):

I created this wiki page so that it can try and keep updated:

[Using libav*](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Using%20libav%2a)

Comment: note that this link was broken by stack overflow's autolinking regex not matching the star at the end of the link - you will need to manually add the star or else copy and paste the link to be taken to the wiki page.

Comment: ok hopefully fixed it, at least for now...

Answer (score 9):

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ is great, but the source code is little dated. For updated code of the tutorial, please take a look here: https://github.com/phamquy/FFmpeg-tutorial-samples

Comment: FYI the dranger.com one appears to have been updated in 2015

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in writing your own ffmpeg format or codec, take a look here:

http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Category:FFmpeg_Tutorials