# C++: FFMPEG and SDL resources

Tags: c++, qt4, ffmpeg, sdl, video-processing

I'm looking for resources (preferably books, but websites are fine too) for using FFmpeg and/or SDL with C++.

**Stuff I'd like to be able to do** (eventually):

- Decode and play videos in realtime to a QT widget (the QT part isn't a problem)
- Overlay text and images on the video (in realtime)
- Loop video
- Cross-fade from one video to another (in realtime)
- Some kind of DVD functionality
- LIVE sources?  (i.e. webcam, stream, etc.)

**So far I've looked at** (and consider helpful) **the following resources:**

- [FFmpeg and SDL Tutorial by Dranger](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) (extremely helpful)
- [Stack Overflow:  ffmpeg C API documentation/tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial)  (not a duplicate, btw)
- Sample code bundled with FFMPEG libraries

  (I'll try and update this list with anything helpful below)

Thanks for any help...

**Also:** Operating System is Windows (but maybe one day cross-platform)
**Also 2:** Resources using alternatives are welcome too... i.e. DirectShow, VFW, etc.

Comment: I updated Dranger's source code here: https://github.com/phamquy/FFmpeg-tutorial-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to decode and play videos and require overlays I would consider using the Phonon framework, and use QT Graphics View by using a Phonon::VideoWidget inside a QGraphicsProxyWidget.  That way you can easily get overlays, cross-fading, animations etc.  Phonon in Windows uses DirectShow as a back-end. You can install FFDShow and get the same codecs ffmpeg has to play videos.

Comment: Based on this post (http://lists.trolltech.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2010-February/019385.html), I was under the impression that it couldn't be done with Phonon.

Comment: (that, and I couldn't find any way to do it in the documentation - it works more like a video player with load and play operations)

Comment: Take a look at this demo 
http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/11/28/videos-get-pimped
Its using Phonon+GfxView to do transparency and fast video transforms.

Answer (score 1):

There is an FFMPEG C++ wrapper library : [FOBS](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/). It is quite simple to use, but what you gain in simplicity you lose in fine grained configuration. It works great but is always a bit outdated.

m2c

Comment: thanks - i'd accept your answer too if I could since I haven't decided yet which I'm going to go with (but I'll probably stay with Phonon if it turns out that it can handle EVERYTHING I want to do)

Comment: You are welcome. I do not know about Phonon. I will perhaps give it a try to compare ... But it seems too tied to KDE to fit my needs.