# FFmpeg API books, tutorial, etc

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ffmpeg C API documentation/tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial)

Hi!
A have a task to write on-line screen recording using FFmpeg library with C++, but I can't find some documentation, manual, textbook etc. I didn't work with audio-video before at all, I don't know how to start, and can't find where to learn it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: it's probably best to start here: http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm a complete newbie in this, but I've read all in their site and documentation, but they have really little information there. There is only description of functions, but there is a lot of them, and I don't what of them I need. Is there nothing like a beginning tutorial to FFmpeg?

Comment: See if any of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial) are helpful to you (it indicates C in the title, but probably because the library itself is in C).

Comment: Mods: the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial) has been closed and is obviously useful. Can someone people vote to reopen or something?

Answer (score 4):

In that case, you should check [these ffmpeg tutorials](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html).

They show how to open a video file, read/write frames, sync audio and video and a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the source is unfortunately the only solution.

For understanding H264 there is the [reference source code](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/) and the [H264 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470848375)