# C api on capturing video stream from webcam using ffmpeg

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, webcam

I am a new user of ffmpeg. Ffmpeg has a good documentation on using it in command-line, but i am looking for some C API code.

I want to make a software using C, that would capture video stream from webcam and give me the video stream in raw format, that I would encode in a codec later.

I have visited this given link, but it provided only the command-line use, not the use of libraries provided by ffmpeg: 
http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20capture%20a%20webcam%20input

I also visited this link, which gave me good idea on using the libavcodec, but no other tutorial is available :
[ffmpeg C API documentation/tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial)

Please someone help me finding C api on video stream capturing from webcam using ffmpeg's library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ffmpeg C API documentation/tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You are basically repeating [the question you are referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial). FFmpeg is basically the name of the library and the ready to use tool (command line interface). Its back end is a set of libraries: libavcodec, libavformat, swscale etc.

There is no comprehensive documentation on these libraries, instead there are samples, there is mailing list and other sparse resources. Also, the libraries are open source and all these are quite usable once you get the pieces together. Specific questions on [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) are asked/answered on StackOverflow as well.