# Access camera Feed Without OpenCV

Tags: c, image-processing

Is there any way to get camera feed as rgb array in c, without using opencv?
I am currently working on an image recognition program from scratch.

I want to use the data in a struct like this:

```
typedef struct CameraFeed
{
int size;
//other data like width and height...
unsigned char* rgbValuesArray;
}
```

Comment: sounds painful. I'd at least use opencv to get the image, then plug in your image recognition code. There is a whole lot of code and a lot of layers in between image recognition and physical camera that have nothing to do with image recognition.

Comment: Did you look at ffmpeg ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639983/c-api-on-capturing-video-stream-from-webcam-using-ffmpeg

Comment: of course there is a way. how do you think the OpenCV guys did it? you don't have to use OpenCV but you should definitely use some library. no need to reinvent the wheel