# How to extract an Image from a video file in qt?

Tags: qt, ffmpeg

I want to extract an image (First frame) form a video file in qt. I used ffmpeg application to extract a frame, it gives extact result what I need, but ffmpeg is a seperate application, which overloads process. So I want to make it as static linking. Is it possible make static link to ffmpeg , is there is any statick library available for extracting frame from video or are there any other ways to extract frame from video? I dont want to use Qt phonon, because it physically opens a phonon dialog and then take a scrrenshot. I want the extracting process should happenin background.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices : either via `ffmpeg` API, or via `ffmpeg` executable. Basically

**Executable Approach:** quick and dirty, not that bad if done correctly, but not very flexible

Call ffmpeg executable via [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html) and then read the processed data from disk. You need to construct ffmpeg command lines parameters from your own parameters; be able to capture the result (failed\succeeded) and .

**API Approach:** long term, clean but require significant amount of work at beginning

- Obtain ffmpeg dynamic librairies (avcodec, etc..)
- Follow a tutorial on how ffmpeg API is used. Dranger is the most well known, and there is an [updated version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial) .*Careful, learning curve ahead*
- incorporate that in your Qt App (pro config, wrapper around your ffmpeg functionality, etc..)
- Build the static library version. I leave it last because I can be annoying, especially if you are on windows (hope you are not)

Personally I will recommend to stick with the executable approach unless you don't mind taking a week to learn `ffmpeg API`.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has a built-in [videocapture API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture), which actually wraps avcodec, easier to work with -in case you dont want to mess with avcodec.

EDIT: [Data conversion](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtOpenCV).