# How to get format of video stream in ffmpeg (c++)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a function that reads frames from a stream. I want to find out what the format of the stream is (I'm testing with H264):

```
StreamingResult MediaWriter::Open(const AVFormatContext *const inputFormatContext,
                                  const fs::path &destination)
{
  // Save input stream data
  AVStream *videoStream = inputFormatContext->streams[FindVideoStreamIndex(inputFormatContext)];
  //....
}
```

How can I get the format/codec type from the video stream? I am expecting to receive H264, but other formats will be received in the future.

P.S.: Some good FFMPEG documentation would be appreciated, because I am getting lost in Doxygen generated documentation.

Comment: You might want to look at the answers/comments from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Some good FFMPEG documentation would be appreciated, because I am getting lost in Doxygen generated documentation.`

Doxygen is th best ffmpeg documentation there is. Its just ffmpeg is a very large peroject and takes time to learn.

What you are looking for is [videoStream](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/structAVStream.html)->[codecpar](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/structAVCodecParameters.html)->[codec_id](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce)