# Libavformat- Passing an object of images to libavformat to generate a video

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec, libavformat

I am trying to generate a video with libavformat/Libavcodec with a bunch of images that are in memory.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, the basics of creating a video from images with FFmpeg is explained [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence).

If you simply want to change/force the format and codec of your video, [here](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/ffmpeg-convert-media-file-formats) is a good start.

For the raw FFmpeg documentation you could use the [Video and Audio Format Conversion](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion), the [Codec Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html), the [Format Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) the  and the [image2 demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-image2-1) (this demuxer will manage images as an input).

If you just want to take images and make a simple video out of it, just look at the 2 first links. FFmpeg's documentation gives you powerful tools but don't use them if you don't need them.

A sample command to create a video from images is:

```
ffmpeg -i image-%03d.png video.mp4
```

This will take all the files in sequence from `image-000.png` to the highest number available and make a video out of it.
You can force the format with the extension of the output file. To force the video codec use `-c:v` followed by a codec name available in the codec documentation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I tried this and it works but now I want to use the libs*.dll that is generated and call an internal function to pass images to generate video. Looking if there is way to do that. Thank you

Comment: Alright, for that you can go to this [page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*) it'll give you access to the libav* documentations and some tips. If you want to find more info or tutorials I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial). They mention a [git repo](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial) that has a few tutorials on using libav* but it seems old. So I found this [other repo](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial) it seems up to date and complete.