# Are there any examples/documentation available that demonstrate how to use FFMPEG libraries directly in Python/C instead of the command line?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, metadata, pyffmpeg, sharpffmpeg

I want to perform the operation done by the below command line of FFMPEG but only using the command line. Instead I want to use the underlying libraries directly in Python and C to perform the operation:

`ffmpeg -i "Filename.ts" -map 0:d -c copy -f data "outputfile.bin" | python ./klvdata_test.py`

The task at hand is to extract the metadata. Are there any examples/documentation demonstrating the use of underlying libraries of FFMPEG.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641460/ffmpeg-c-api-documentation-tutorial).

Comment: ffmpeg uses libav internally and executes any command by one or more function calls from libav. Is there a way to traceback which functions are called from the libav library for each command line script of ffmpeg? @HernánAlarcón

Comment: Not that I know.