# Using libav without command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, command, libav

I use this command below for converting file

`./avconv -i inputFile -vcodec libx264 -trellis 2 -crf 23 -tune psnr -vf crop='trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2' -y outputFile`

But, I don't want to use this command, I want to make a function like

`convert(char *inputFile, char *outputFile). (The option of my function like option in command line)`

And then I will call it from my main function 
for example

```
int main(){ 
    convert(in01, out01); 
    convert(in02, out02); 
    convert(in03, out03); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program). But it is not clear to me.
Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? I have googled many times but did not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Linux OS ...

The solution to your question is more about how to execute a process in C. So, not to do with ffmpeg but to do with programming in Linux C.

Basically you need to first 'fork' a process from your C function, then exchange (exec) the forked process with 'avconv' and pass the arguments into this process.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html