# Running ffmpeg as library in android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg, dynamic-linking

I've got a simple task to do. I need to merge set of pictures into a video using ffmpeg working in android environment.

After over a week fighting with different tutorials and examples explaining how to run compile  ffmpeg I have, let's say, middle success. I've finally compiled ffmpeg for android.

I followed this example:
https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg
which worked best for me.

As a result of building ffmpeg a have following directory structure:

```
[Project]/jni/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so
[Project]/jni/ffmpeg-build/armeabi/libffmpeg.so
[Project]/jni/ffmpeg-build/mips/libffmpeg.so
[Project]/jni/ffmpeg-build/x86/libffmpeg.so
```

I also followed the ndk examples so I have running c code from java:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>    
#include <android/log.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool initted = false;    
static JavaVM *sVm;

jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {

    char **argv;
    char *cmd;
    int argc;

//  cmd = "ffmpeg -version";
//  argv = parsedargs(cmd, &argc);
//  ffmpeg(argc, argv);

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");

}
```

My question is how to run function from ffmpeg from my "hello-jni" c-file. I've read I need to write a wrapper over ffmpeg which my hello-jni is intended to be.

Here is my Android.mk which probably is importat part to achieve my goal, but honestly I don't understand some lines set in this file. Or simply I don't know how to make things work.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := true
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=true
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := ffmpeg-prebuilt
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -Iffmpeg-prebuilt -Ihello-jni -Wno-deprecated-declarations 
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz -landroid ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libffmpeg.so 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

One more thing. I've found an example how to wrap ffmpeg's main function. It'd be the easiest way to use ffmpeg for me sinse I don't know ffmpeg's api and I hope it's possible to run ffmpeg this way:
[Can FFmpeg be used as a library, instead of a standalone program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program)

To sum up, I think my problems are due to completely lack of c/c++ knowledge at all, especially how to use run any function from .so library.

I hope someone can help me :).

Comment: You could try the binaries bundled in [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/). There are also instructions on how to build them.

Comment: what about stopping/canceling execution? do you know a solution how to stop FFmpeg after you called ffmpeg's main function?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/videokit/uk_co_halfninja_videokit_Videokit.c

Look at the 'JNI_Call...' in the link above. That is how to call the wrapper for 'ffmpeg.main()' from android.

https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/videokit/ffmpeg.c

use link above and find 'main()' at the very end. This is example of  very slightly altered version of ffmpeg.c  (logger altered for java/android ndk).

If you study these samples , you should get feeling for how to wrapper ffmpeg.main() in one of the other projects if you want to use it. The logger issue is moot at this point so the more modern [android-ffmpeg] projects on git can just make ffmpeg.c out of the box and use it with JNI. The only thing u may still have to change is the 'exit()' at the very end of main().

Comment: Hi Robert, I am trying to compile LGPL version of ffmpeg for android and am following this post. However, I dont understand why you have mentioned that i still have to change is the exit() at the very end of main(). In halfninja project they still have the exit_program(0) over there, right? Why is it required to make the change and what should i change it to ??

Comment: the halfninja version of the ffmpeg submodule is 'd0A2...'     are u using that commit ... NO  . so the comment would not apply to you and your ffmpeg.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use ffmpeg for video compression. But since you have mentioned that i need to change the exit at the very end of main(), that is the reason i am wondering why I need to do so?
what might be the consequences if i use ffmpeg.c's main() as it is. ??

Comment: https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/videokit/ffmpeg.c#L4938   is the exit i was referring to.  This was not in the earlier ffmpeg code back at that time and may have been necessary to get a clean exit and lib unload within android jni stack.