# Stream OpenCV output as emulated webcam?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, video, webcam

Im working with the Intel Realsense Camera which outputs video in PXCImage format. I want to read this in Java or C++, convert it to OpenCV Mat format and stream it live as a webcam stream which can be read by any other webcam application.

Ive found code to read and convert the stream to Mat format, but Im stuck at the part where I have to output it as a webcam stream so it can be read by any arbitrary application.

Is there any way in C++ or java to emulate a webcam and output video through it ?

Comment: Hi, I also have the same problem with streaming using Java and OpenCV, did you solve your problem? If yes, then how? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to re-stream the video [`ffserver`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) would help. It's part of `ffmpeg` package which is a standalone application but with some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program) can also be called from C/C++.

Alternatively you can use [`kurento`](https://www.kurento.org/) media server which allows you to write custom OpenCV plugin for manipulating the video stream.

Comment: No, I want to process the video in Java before streaming. The stream should be seen as a webcam stream in the same PC.

Comment: @KarthiKeyan were you able to figure this out? I am looking to do something similar. Thanks