# Python3: emulate local webcam device with OpenCV on win10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, opencv, emulation, webcam

I want to stream my processed OpenCV output in Python as a local webcam stream so it can be used by other programs as any other webcam. Is it possible? Are there any libraries that can do it?

I've read through some stackoverflow questions and found this: [Stream OpenCV output as emulated webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827867/stream-opencv-output-as-emulated-webcam) that is pretty similar to my problem (but in Java/C++)

instead of doing:

```
cv2.imshow("...", output)
```

every frame I want to have a stream that I can supply images and that would then be considered as a webcam by other programs.

Comment: I think you can take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480034/how-to-simulate-a-webcam-device). This answers a similar question.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it

Answer (score 0):

I also went through this trouble and believe me I got a really better solution for every platform.

Just install droidcam on your machine. Find the port it uses to connect with the mobile application. Normally it is port 4747. Then just connect to it using the python socket. Start the server on the local host and port 4747. It will connect and stream video to that.

Droid cam can be used with any other software like Zoom.