# How to concatenate two mp4 files using ffmpeg C code?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I found many links about concatenating multiple mp4 files using ffmpeg command on shell environment. Such as:

[Concatenate two mp4 files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)

But I didn't find any information about using C code. There are some code snippet, but it seems not working.

```
static int setargs(char *args, char **argv)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (isspace(*args)) ++args;
    while (*args) {
        if (argv) argv[count] = args;
        while (*args && !isspace(*args)) ++args;
        if (argv && *args) *args++ = '\0';
        while (isspace(*args)) ++args;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

char **parsedargs(char *args, int *argc)
{
    char **argv = NULL;
    int    argn = 0;

    if (args && *args
        && (args = strdup(args))
        && (argn = setargs(args,NULL))
        && (argv = malloc((argn+1) * sizeof(char *)))) {
          *argv++ = args;
          argn = setargs(args,argv);
    }

    if (args && !argv) free(args);

    *argc = argn;
    return argv;
}

void freeparsedargs(char **argv)
{
    if (argv) {
        free(argv[-1]);
        free(argv-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **argv;
    char *cmd;
    int argc;

    cmd = "ffmpeg -i infile outfile";
    argv = parsedargs(cmd,&argc);
    ffmpeg(argc, argv);
}
```

[Can FFmpeg be used as a library, instead of a standalone program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program)

How to do it by using ffmpeg C code ?

Comment: Google 'ffmpeg dranger'

Comment: visit here to create mp4 video using c++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, did you find any answer?