# how to apply a ffmpeg command on all video within a repository?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have written the following command which changes the resolution and frame per second rate of the input video,
I want to apply this command on all my videos in my video repository

any help would be appreciated

```
ffmpeg -i C:\vid2.mp4 -an -r 10 -filter:v "setpts=01.0*PTS" -vf scale=320:240 C:\vid320_200fps10.mp4
```

Comment: [possible dulicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200370/2286337)

Comment: I asked this question, cause I want to  learn something new, I think advance peaple has to help beginner one, instead Sir

Comment: You have to write a code, plz take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program)

Comment: Adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273691/1109017).