# Run FFmpeg as a separate process for an application

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, ipc

Assume I have an app for Android and the same app for iOS. In both cases, my app needs to use [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) features. I decided to avoid calling `libavcodec` and `libavformat` directly. Instead, I'm going to implement [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program#comment2381621_2401764):

> IMHO running `ffmpeg` in a separate process is a better idea, so your application won't be stuck while the lengthy process of video encoding goes.

What's the standard approach to run `ffmpeg` in a separate process on each platform? What's the standard way to communicate with it?

Comment: I think for Android, the best approach now are Coroutines.

Comment: 10 years later, it's a bad idea to run **ffmpeg** as separate process on Android, and it has never been a viable option on iOS. I suggest that you look at the [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) library that wraps the ffmpeg in a library that can be used similar to the ffmpeg CLI for Android and iOS apps.

Comment: @AlexCohn Looks good =) the only drawback is that its API is in Objective-C, not Swift!

Comment: I never heard of problems in calling Obj-C from Swift, but if you have, you can open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: are you looking for something like `service`?